# What is the difference between SWK, SWJ, and SWP (Stanley Black & Decker)

Tags: investing, stock-markets, bonds

Stanley Black & Decker seems to have three symbols on the NYSE.

- SWK: Stanley Black & Decker, Inc.
- SWP: Stanley Black & Decker, Inc. CORP UNIT 2017
- SWJ: Stanley Black & Decker, Inc. JR SUB DEB 52

SWK seems to me to be straight forward company stock.  But I do not really understand what SWP and SWJ, or why I might want to invest in them.  This makes it hard for me to valuate SWK since I do not understand how the holdings in SWP and SWJ might influence the company's financial standing or where those shares might stand in priority.

Can someone give a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWK is the common stock of  Stanley Black & Decker

SWJ is the  5.750% Junior Subordinated Debenture (1.4375 annual dividend).  It was issued at $25, is callable at any time and matures on 7/25/2052.

SWP  is a 5.375% Equity Unit due 6/2020 which includes a stock purchase contract and a 1/10 undivided beneficial ownership interest in a 0% Series C Cumulative Perpetual Convertible Preferred Stock, no later than 5/15/2020.    There are multiple price considerations that depend on the share price  and you can read the prospectus at: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/93556/000119312517170874/d376195d424b2.htm